# Locking a Java application to a particular PC

Tags: java, security

I want to devise a way to prevent piracy of my app or at least make it more difficult. The app will be installed in a standalone PC and I want to make it difficult for a person to simply copy the installation,  or clone the hard drive,  and simply deploy it on a second PC.
Is using the MAC address the best way?  What about using WMI to get a mother board ID?

Comment: you have already lost ...

Comment: How determined/skilled an attacker do you need to defeat?  Are they likely to intercept and reinterpret the system calls that `java.lang.Runtime` and `java.io.*` use to check such things?  Do you need to worry about the Java app being installed on cloned VMWare instances that report the same machine identifiers?

Comment: Is your application really worth that much to put the effort in? If it isn't, why bother? If it is, someone will easily crack it and that's your effort wasted.

Comment: Depending on how secure you need it to be, you may want to look into a [software protection fob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_protection_dongle). It's old school, annoying, and expensive but they do work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a Machine ID based on the mac address of the network card, or based on the PC  name (weaker protection), and then make an algorithm that translate a Machine ID into an Activation Key.

So you can activate a program based on an unique identifier based on a PC. *However there is no easy way to calculate a unique Machine ID in JAva ...* If you run your Application only on Windows you can read some other hardware values from [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and mix(for example you could mix HD Serial + MB serial + CPU Serial + Mac Address) them into one key this should enforce a better protection.

Keep in mind that if you put a protection system in your application you should also at least obfuscate your bytecode, because java bytecode is easily decompilable and one programmer that will decompile your application will be able to discover and use the algoritm that you integrated for the validation code ...

Answer (score 1):

I personally feel that using identifiers within the machine is not very friendly to your customer.  What happens when they get a new machine and want to install the software they legally purchased on their new machine?

If you are going to implement something like this I believe it is better to generate some sort of installation key and have it sent to a webservice that you manage.  You can then see if a certain key is being heavily used and deactivate it.

Answer (score 1):

Normal java means do not exist to my knowledge. For instance the UUID which normally should hash using the MAC address, does not so in the java implementation. What you can do, is distribute the application via **WebStart**, providing a regular update mechanism and do a license check.